# Erro ao gravar arquivo stream

Tags: c#, .net, arquivo, stream

> O fluxo não era gravável

Recebe essa exceção ao tentar alterar um arquivo que esta no *resource*. Segue o código:

```
var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        Stream str = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("PCCLC9875.versao.txt");

        String linha = "versao=" + INICIAL_VERSAO + ";revisao=00;compilacao=00";
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(str);
        sw.WriteLine(linha);
        sw.Close();
        str.Close();
```

Só consigo fazer a leitura, mas ao tentar alterar da erro.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Esse *stream* foi disponibilizado só para leitura mesmo, não pode tentar gravá-lo. O erro diz explicitamente isto.

Se quiser mexer nos metadados do *assembly* até é possível, mas é preciso cuidado e entender todas implicações, que não são poucas.

Apenas para iniciar o estudo sobre o assunto:

- [Setting Assembly attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/assembly/set-attributes?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397)
- [AssemblyBuilder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.emit.assemblybuilder?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-8.0)

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Saquei, achei que faltava alguma manobra nesse código pra funcionar.  Vlw